# retrieve Hashmap Elements by index based

Tags: java, indexing, hashmap

```
Map pins = new HashMap();
pins.put("t1","test1");
pins.put("t2","test2");
pins.put("t3","test3");
pins.put("t4","test4");
```

Here is my code,i store key and values in HashMap.

And i want to retrieve key and value by index value just like array.

Retrieve value by key using iterator working.

But i want index based can any body help me please.

Comment: Please show some code/effort, and also mention to us what language you're using (Java/C#?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you will have to use `LinkedHashMap`.

```
Map pins = new LinkedHashMap();
```

and then after putting in the values, you can do the following:

```
List keys = new ArrayList(pins.keySet());
List values = new ArrayList(pins.values());
System.out.print((String)keys.get(0) + " " + (String)values.get(0));
```

Comment: but i need to store two values and get them by index

Comment: ok i changed the above statements 
i need to store two values at a time

Comment: ok i will explain
i have pin_id and its value (suppose they are 10)
i need to access by with index not pin_id